# Parsing out parts of a string in an array in Java

Tags: java, parsing, arraylist

I'm having trouble finding a solution in parsing out a particular part of each item in an `Arraylist`.

The `Arraylist` contains strings in both these formats:

`http://some-url.com/that/goes-to-some-place-abc-defg/api/xml
 http://some-url.com/that/goes-to-somewhere-zyxw-vut/api/xml`

The key point is that the string won't change, the only thing that will be different in each of these is the *"abc-defg"* and *"zyxw-vut"*. Note that they may be anything of varying length. This is the part I need to parse out to use elsewhere.

Only idea I've had is writing something to parse out everything after the 5th  hyphen up to the next "/" for the former and the 4th to the next "/" for the latter.

I'm not sure how to do this though and there's likely a better method I haven't thought of.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could just save the "random" parts in the ArrayList. This would save memory since the rest of the string is always the same:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
//Add your random parts
list.add("abc-defg");
list.add("zyxw-vut");
/* ... */
```

And when you want to get a full link from the list, you use a helper method:

```
private String getLinkFromList(int index) {
    if (list == null || index < 0 || index >= list.size())
        return null;
    return "http://some-url.com/that/goes-to-somewhere-" + list.get(index) + "/api/xml";
}
```

**A few notes:**
This solution also has a few downsides: Memory is always allocated when the `getLinkFromList(int)` method is called. When you save the full link in the ArrayList and always just use the `get(int)` method from the ArrayList, you have a slight performance gain. If that list is not larger than a few MegaBytes and your code is only running on (modern) computers, then you should prefer saving the full link.
But when your code is running on an android phone (or when your list is a few GigaBytes large), where memory is still an important thing to consider, then you should make your list as small as possible and use my method as shown above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The problem with this is that the 'random parts' come from the whole string, they aren't in a location where I can get at them. It's from XML which will be ever-changing with new additions. Adding the 'random.parts' into an ArrayList is something I want to do but I need to get them from the ArrayList containing the whole link. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `split("\\/") ;`

This will return an array of String objects split along the `/` separator.

[String.split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

For example for your String : `http://some-url.com/that/goes-to-some-place-abc-defg/api/xml`

This will return an array of size 7 , the content of the array would be :

```
http:

some-url.com
that
goes-to-some-place-abc-defg
api
xml
```

What you want is the index 4 of this array.

Note that index 1 is empty, this comes from the split of the `//` part.